# YouTube Data API search limit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube Data API v3 and I tried to find videos published within certain period like below link.

```
part : snippet
regionCode : KR
relevanceLanguage : KO
publishedAfter: 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z
publishedBefore: 2020-01-02T00:00:00Z
type : video
order : date
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22order%22%3A%22title%22%2C%22publishedAfter%22%3A%222020-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22publishedBefore%22%3A%222020-01-01T02%3A00%3A00Z%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22KR%22%2C%22relevanceLanguage%22%3A%22KO%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22video%22%2C%22videoCategoryId%22%3A%2215%22%7D

But the result seems to be limited to 500. So I tried to see when the 500th video was published.
If I memory the time, I can put that time into publishedAfter and extract another 500. 
but oddly enough, the 500th video's published time was almost "2020-01-02T00:00:00Z", the publishedBefore.

```
first video published time : 2020-01-01T23:53:57.000Z
last 500th video published time : 2020-01-01T00:00:02.000Z
```

The total result is more than 6000. But within first 500 videos, all publishing time within publishedAfter and publishedBefore appear. So where did the remaining 5500 videos go?

Comment: the max rows returned by search list is 50 you need to use the next page token to get additional rows.

Comment: I already used the next page token. so I found 500th video.

Comment: total results is an estimate if thats what your worried about.   its not very accurate

Comment: Is there a big gap like that?

Comment: I have seen a total results of 1000000 and only been able to get back 25000.